# About accessing Ubuntu on hard disk by some other way

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Phoenix OS alongside my Ubuntu and set that Phoenix OS as default operating system in grub customizer. Now it can't detect my Phoenix OS . Also I can't access my Ubuntu. So is their any other way to access Ubuntu and change the grub customizer so that I can change my default operating system back to Ubuntu from Phoenix?
Please help!

Comment: If the grub is not working, can't you just use the boot keys of your machine during startup and choose the OS?

Comment: No. Because I have selected Phoenix OS as default from grub-customizer inside Ubuntu . So , whenever I try boot in to Ubuntu it leads me to Phoenix OS.

Comment: I don't know phoenix OS, so can't advise with it. If I was happy with phoenix and it has a boot loader like `grub`, I'd have it update it's `grub.cfg` (`update-grub` in Ubuntu terms) and see if it recognizes Ubuntu; if it does I'd consider making it own the boot (ie. have it write the boot loader or `grub-install` in Ubuntu terms). Alternatively or more probably firstly, I'd boot a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media) & ensure everything looks good. I'd likely reboot & use "E" (edit) on grub to have it boot Ubuntu ('live' will tell you where Ubuntu is) then have it `upgrade-grub`